# After moving website, edit & create modules,menu not working

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I moved website on 
http://development.artisla.com

Front end is working fine but on the backend, when i click on edit, or want to add a module or menu or user it redirects me to the previous page & checked in that module or menu or user.

Kindly guide me how can avoid this, to work it perfectly.

Below are the temporary credentials.

what i noticed is it shows me the below warning, but when i checked that lines there is nothing wrong with that

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at    /home/artisla/public_html/development/plugins/system/regacymailing/regacymailing.php:15) in /home/artisla/public_html/development/components/com_community/libraries/core.php on line 1191

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/artisla/public_html/development/plugins/system/regacymailing/regacymailing.php:15) in /home/artisla/public_html/development/libraries/joomla/session/session.php on line 565

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/artisla/public_html/development/plugins/system/regacymailing/regacymailing.php:15) in /home/artisla/public_html/development/libraries/joomla/application/application.php on line 836
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by a too high setting for PHP ([see error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)). Also check your error logs for more details.

- A good starting point would be to disable the plugin Acymailing / regacymailing to see if the problem goes away.
- You are using an outdated version of Joomla!, please update it.
- Update the Acymailing  extension to the latest version

Comment: amazing thing is for me all same settings is work on live website

www.artisla.com